# How can I check if my hosting provider blocked outbound traffic to some IP's?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, ip-address, firewall

I have a website powered by WordPress and I am using MailChimp with the official WP plugin. I know this plugin works as its very popular and it works on my other hosting account but not on this site. I suspect my host is blocking.

How can I check if my hosting provider blocked outbound traffic to some IP addresses?

Comment: Do you have SSH access?? If so, try ping or curl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The best method would be to ask your hosting provider, but if you have SSH access you could do a simple ping, curl or even traceroute. If you do not have SSH access then you may be able to run this PHP script:*

> [SOURCE](https://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/check-your-server-status-a-basic-ping-with-php/)
>
> ```
> if (!$file) $status = -1;  // Site is down
> else {
>     fclose($file);
>     $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
>     $status = floor($status);
> }
> return $status; } ?>   
> <DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html> <body>
>   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="domain">
>     Domain name:
>     <table>
>       <input name="domainname" type="text" >
>       <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Ping domain">
>     </table>
>   </form> <?php
> // Check whether the for was submitted
> if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
>     $domainbase = (isset($_POST['domainname'])) ? $_POST['domainname'] : '';
>     $domainbase = str_replace("http://","",strtolower($domainbase));
>
>     echo '<table>';
>
>     $status = pingDomain($domainbase);
>     if ($status != -1) echo "<tr><td>http://$domainbase is ALIVE ($status ms)</td><tr>";
>     else  echo "<tr><td>http://$domainbase is DOWN</td><tr>";
>
>      echo '</table>';
> } ?> </body> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Speak to the hosting provider and ask them if they do outbound IP or DNS blocking and if so what the policy with those blocks are. There could be a DNS issue connecting to mailchimp, or could be a firewall restriction. They may be blocking access to mailchimp for fear of it being used by webmasters to send spam in which case they may allow access if you provide them the reason for needing it. If they are not restricting access then they will be able to chase it up and check server and firewall logs to see what the problem is and if it is in their control get it fixed for you.